# Excel VBA Code Race Condition Not Fixed by Wait, Sleep, DoEvents, etc

Tags: excel, race-condition, vba

### SOLVED! See the code below for the solution!

I have an Excel file containing multiple shape objects next to a series of text. I wrote a script to identify the location of each shape, identify how many cells to the right and down the text extends to, sets that as a range and then imports that into a chart object so I can save it as a .jpg.

The trouble is that between the creation of the chart and the pasting of the string there exists a Race Condition. If I step through the script it works fine, but as soon as I run it I get nothing but blank images.

I've tried Application.ScreenUpdating = True; Application.PrintCommunication = True; and DoEvents

I've also tried Application.Wait, but even having it wait ten seconds doesn't do the trick, when stepping through the code the chart is loaded in less than 2 seconds.

Recently I tried the kernel32 sleep method as well, and that doesn't seem to work either. Again, the amount of time I let the system sleep far exceeded my stepping. I also added all of the above methods between each line within the With statement (obviously not as a solution, but as a test) and that didn't work either..

At this point I'm completely at a loss.

If I place a stop at .Chart.Paste and then run the script (F5), and just keep hitting Run then the script works wonderfully. I just don't want users to have to sit there and hit run 600 times.

There are obvious redundancies written in between the creation of the chart and pasting of the text. This is all in the attempt at getting the code to work properly when run, and once a solution is found most of that code will be removed.

```
    Option Explicit

    Public Function ChartCheck() As String

    ReCheckChart:
    DoEvents
    If ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count > 0 Then
    GoTo ContinuePaste:
    Else
    GoTo ReCheckChart:
    ContinuePaste:
    End If

    End Function


    Public Function GetFolder() As String

    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String

    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fldr
        .Title = "Select a Folder to Save the Images In"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show  -1 Then GoTo NextCode:
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
    NextCode:
    GetFolder = sItem
    Set fldr = Nothing

    End Function


    Private Sub DNImageExtraction_Click()

    Dim fileName                As String
    Dim targetWorkbook          As Excel.Workbook
    Dim targetWorksheet         As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim saveLocation            As Variant
    Dim saveName                As String
    Dim targetShape             As Shape
    Dim workingRange            As Excel.Range
    Dim bottomRow               As Long
    Dim workingRangeWidth       As Double
    Dim workingRangeHeight      As Double
    Dim tempChart               As ChartObject

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    DNImageExtraction.AutoSize = False  'This is necessary to prevent the system I use from altering the font on the button
    DNImageExtraction.AutoSize = True
    DNImageExtraction.Height = 38.4
    DNImageExtraction.Left = 19.2
    DNImageExtraction.Width = 133.8

    fileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xls*),*.xls*", , "Please select Excel file...")

    Set targetWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(fileName)
    Set targetWorksheet = targetWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    saveLocation = GetFolder

    For Each targetShape In targetWorksheet.Shapes

        Set workingRange = targetWorksheet.Cells(targetShape.TopLeftCell.Row, targetShape.TopLeftCell.Column).Offset(1, 0)

        saveName = workingRange.Text

        If workingRange.Offset(0, 1).Value  "" Then
            If workingRange.Offset(1, 1).Value = "" Then
                Set workingRange = Nothing
                Set workingRange = targetWorksheet.Cells(targetShape.TopLeftCell.Row, targetShape.TopLeftCell.Column).Resize(, 2)
            Else
                bottomRow = workingRange.Offset(0, 1).End(xlDown).Row
                Set workingRange = targetWorksheet.Cells(targetShape.TopLeftCell.Row, targetShape.TopLeftCell.Column).Resize((bottomRow + 2 - workingRange.Row), 2)
            End If

            workingRangeWidth = workingRange.Width
            workingRangeHeight = workingRange.Height
        End If

        workingRange.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlPrinter, Format:=xlPicture

        Set tempChart = targetWorksheet.ChartObjects.Add(0, 0, workingRangeWidth, workingRangeHeight)


    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.PrintCommunication = True
    DoEvents
    Call ChartCheck

            tempChart.Chart.Paste
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            tempChart.Chart.Export fileName:=saveLocation & "\DN " & saveName & ".jpg", Filtername:="JPG"
            tempChart.Delete
        Set tempChart = Nothing

    Next

    Application.Workbooks(targetWorkbook.Name).Close savechanges:=False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Any assistance in either a solution to the Race Condition, or re organizing the script to avoid the Race Condition altogether would be greatly appreciated.

(Code above was updated per suggestions made by Macro Man, and then re-modified once again to add in all previous suggestions on how to fix Race Condition issues after the changes were not effective.)

Comment: As an update, I set up a call to kernel32 for a sleep procedure and set it to 10 seconds. For some reason that didn't work either.. I am confident that the issue either comes from the load time of the chart before pasting, or else the time it takes to paste before the chart is saved.. Either way I have not been successful in getting the code to work when Run.

Comment: One more comment. If I put a stop procedure on .Chart.Paste and hit run for each iteration the code works fine. It needs to stop on that Paste procedure, however no matter how long of a pause I use it doesn't do the trick.

Comment: Are you running it on excel for windows or Excel for Mac?

Comment: Windows on a Surface Pro 4.

Comment: What if you use `set tmpChart = .ChartObjects.Add(0, 0, w, h)` instead of using a one liner and a `With`?

Comment: Ok, so I tried the above (changing .ChartObject to include the Application.Workbooks(wkbname).Worksheets(wksname).ChartObjects.Add(0,0,w,h) but I still get blank images when I run it, and pictures when I step. I like the shorter script for it though, thank you.

Comment: Try commenting out the lines "Application.ScreenUpdating = False" and "Application.DisplayAlerts = False" and "On Error Resume Next" and see whether any useful error messages have been suppressed.

Comment: @LordPeter I've just re-checked that. I have DisplayAlerts off only because I keep testing the same document and I keep getting the warning about losing unsaved progress. The Error I can remove entirely. That was an issue with the past rendition of the program and I don't receive any now. ScreenUpdating is turned back on, and then off midway through the script.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider using  [`Application.OnTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-ontime-method-excel) which is good feature.  It allows the scheduling of some code to be run at a certain time, most often one adds a few seconds to the current time.

Excel VBA is single-threaded and so there is no real synchronization but there is a message pump to keep order.   The great thing about `Application.OnTime` is that it will not run despite being scheduled until the current graph of code has completed.

Because `Application.OnTime` uses the message pump as that is a FIFO structure it is possible to interleave the execution of code.

I think this might help here.

You can schedule a "hasItFinished" procedure which checks the existence of the shape/chart objects and if not re-schedules itself.

P.S. Can be a little tricky to debug, refactor as much code as possible outside of the procedure that you will schedule and unit test them separately.  Please don't expect the lovely Edit,Debug and Continue flow that you normally get with VBA if you go down this path.

Comment: So this suggestion also gave me an idea to use If Application.Workbooks(wkbname).Worksheets(wksname).ChartObjects.Count > 0 Then and loop it until it's >0... unfortunately this didn't fix the issue. I haven't checked Application.OnTime yet.

Comment: I'm having trouble using Application.OnTime. I've never used it before so I'm unfamiliar with how to call in the procedure when I have no other macros to run, unless you are suggesting I add in a macro that essentially does nothing but pause the system briefly to see if that allows the chart to load. Is that what you suggest?

Comment: FANTASTIC! So I created a new Public Function, moved my chartcheck procedure into that function, then put a DoEvent after the call to that function and now it works wonderfully! Thank you so much.

Comment: Bounty can be issued in a couple hours. Currently not able to apply. Just an FYI, I did NOT use the Application.OnTime method because it wasn't necessary, but your suggestion DID lead to calling a public function which works.

Answer (score 2):

Try getting rid of the error handlers and labels, and working with objects directly instead of searching through workbook/worksheet collections. Also using meaningful variable names and proper indentation will help follow the code easily should you have any issues.

If your code works when stepping through, that usually suggests there is some issue with the use of `ActiveWorkbook` when workbooks are being opened/closed. Working with workbooks as objects allows us to overcome that problem because no matter if the workbook is active or not, we are always using the same *instance* of that workbook.

```
Private Sub DNImageExtraction_Click()

    Dim fileName                As String
    Dim targetWorkbook          As Excel.Workbook
    Dim targetWorksheet         As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim saveLocation            As Variant
    Dim saveName                As String
    Dim targetShape             As Shape
    Dim workingRange            As Excel.Range
    Dim bottomRow               As Long
    Dim workingRangeWidth       As Double
    Dim workingRangeHeight      As Double
    Dim tempChart               As ChartObject

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    fileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xls*),*.xls*", , "Please select Excel file...")

    Set targetWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(fileName)
    Set targetWorksheet = targetWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    saveLocation = GetFolder

    For Each targetShape In targetWorksheet.Shapes

        Set workingRange = targetWorksheet.Cells(targetShape.TopLeftCell.Row, targetShape.TopLeftCell.Column).Offset(1, 0)

        saveName = workingRange.Text

        If workingRange.Offset(0, 1).value <> "" Then
            If workingRange.Offset(1, 1).value = "" Then
                Set workingRange = Nothing
                Set workingRange = targetWorksheet.Cells(targetShape.TopLeftCell.Row, targetShape.TopLeftCell.Column).Resize(, 2)
            Else
                bottomRow = workingRange.Offset(0, 1).End(xlDown).Row
                Set workingRange = targetWorksheet.Cells(targetShape.TopLeftCell.Row, targetShape.TopLeftCell.Column).Resize((bottomRow + 2 - workingRange.Row), 2)
            End If

            workingRangeWidth = workingRange.Width
            workingRangeHeight = workingRange.Height
        End If

        workingRange.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlPrinter, Format:=xlPicture

        Set tempChart = targetWorksheet.ChartObjects.Add(0, 0, workingRangeWidth, workingRangeHeight)

        With tempChart
            .Chart.Paste
            .Chart.Export FileName:=saveLocation & "\DN " & saveName & ".jpg", Filtername:="JPG"
            .Delete
        End With

        Set tmpChart = Nothing

        DoEvents

    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Helpful suggestions on streamlining, but unfortunately has the same result. Blank images.

Comment: I updated my own code to match yours for simplicity purposes. This does not fix the issue, but does look cleaner, so thank you.

Comment: @mkinson when you step through this version of the code does it work?

Comment: Yes, it will work when stepping through same as the older version of the code.